# PHP: How to access a namespace class with :: instead of \?

Tags: php, oop, namespaces, php-5.3, spl-autoload-register

I use `namespace` for a class like this below,

class_tidy.php,

```
namespace foo;

class tidy {
    public function hello() {
        echo 'Hello';
    }
}
```

index.php,

```
class MyAutoloader
{
    public static function load($className)
    {
        $parts = explode('\\', $className);
        require 'classes/class_'.end($parts) . '.php';
    }
}

spl_autoload_register("\MyAutoloader::load");

$test = new foo\tidy();
$test->hello();
```

It works perfectly, but I wonder if I can access the class, instead of,

```
$test = new foo\tidy();
```

But,

```
$test = new foo::tidy();
```

Which looks prettier. but with this error,

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING, expecting T_VARIABLE
>   or '$' ...

Comment: Wouldn't it be nice if we could make up our own syntax as we go along?

Comment: Why would you want to implement a syntax that is already used elsewhere? i.e. `foo\tidy::hello();`

Comment: this - http://www.willfitch.com/using-php-namespaces.html

Comment: and tihs http://blog.felho.hu/whats-new-in-php-53-part-1-namespaces.html it looks better with :: I think.

Comment: Both of those articles were written when namespaces were still in development for php. They were written from the point of view of people who thought it was going to work with `::`. It turned out they were wrong.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't. The PHP syntax uses `\` for namespaces.

As a matter of fact, php uses the T_PAAMAYIM_NEKUDOTAYIM (which is their name for the double colon) for only one thing, using it after a class name to specify you want a member of that class.

I do believe there are some obscure details in the way this works which prevented PHP from using it as the namespace sperator as well, but I do not know which. (The thing is that this would mean that even if you branched from the official php and made your own version, you would have to go through a lot of work just to get that slight syntax change you want.)

Comment: but I don't understand - how this person does it - http://blog.felho.hu/whats-new-in-php-53-part-1-namespaces.html

Comment: He doesn't. It was written before namespaces worked at all by someone who thought that was going to be the syntax. The future proved him wrong.

Comment: behavior can maybe be emulated using the magic __call method and making foo a class, but in my opinion that is no good solution.

Answer (score 1):

The php team choose \ as the namespace separator. Even if you think :: is better you cannot change it.
May I ask you why you would that?

Comment: But how this person does it - http://blog.felho.hu/whats-new-in-php-53-part-1-namespaces.html

Comment: Come on: This article is _years_ old and came out, when 5.3 were in an _very_early_ development state. There is even a link right below a big "UPDATE" at the beginning of the article: http://www.willfitch.com/php-namespace-update.html

Comment: He doesn't any more. As this comment: http://blog.felho.hu/whats-new-in-php-53-part-1-namespaces.html#comment-30352 states, it was changed to \ in PHP 5.3 alpha3.

Comment: See this comment http://blog.felho.hu/whats-new-in-php-53-part-1-namespaces.html#comment-30352 It was change since PHP 5.3 alpha3.

Answer (score 1):

Read the official manual: http://php.net/language.namespaces.nested
`::` is not supported as namespace separator, because it's already used (and therefore reserved) as [scope resolution operator](http://php.net/language.oop5.paamayim-nekudotayim)

```
Foo::$bar;
```

Also interesting: The corresponding RFC https://wiki.php.net/rfc/namespaceseparator

Comment: Not using :: "because" it's already used as a scope resolution operator is a pretty nonsensical reason.  After all, namespaces *are* a scope resolution system, and the current use for :: in PHP is like a half-witted scope system.  What language doesn't include namespaces until version 5.3?